# Session between different browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I am Working in ASP.NET MVC4 web application using Forms Authentication.
I have an application where user logs in to enter the application, if a user opens the application in a browser and logs in,and if user opens the application in some other browser in the same system they should not allow to logged in and give alert message as "User is already logged in a different browser". The same should happen within the same browser in different tabs and also in the different instance of same browser in which user was Previously logged in.
Please give me Your suggestions.....

Comment: This is tricky. You might want to use local storage of the browser to identified which browser that the user is currently using.

Comment: You could try to save the SessionId somewhere(DB maybe) and check if user is already logged in by sessionid.  But on the same browser? that's just not possible I think.

Comment: The basic problem is distinguishing if a user has clicked a link or if he typed the address in a new tab. I see no reliable way that an experienced user could not copy. But please think about whether you really want to do this. We use an application that does a similar thing. It invalidates old pages if a new page is opened (via a time stamp check). But it is a pain working with it. You should really try to make your application multi-tab compatible.